# Why can't I get a D with stroke?

Tags: symbols

The Comprehensive Latex Symbol list tells me that I can't get `Đ` with `OT1` using the command `\DJ`, and that I need `T1` font encoding. When I use `[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble, this doesn't work either.

So how do I get `Đ`?

Comment: It works on my machine. Please edit your question and add an example code that reproduces the problem. Without this it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Works on my machine.  Are you sure you called `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
`

Comment: As well, try `\usepackage{lmodern}` and possibly, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and then directly the symbol `Đ` as it appears in the question.

Answer (score 6):

A minimal example producing your symbol (D stroke, unicode `U+0110`) is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\DJ
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Should there be some reason you do not wish to load T1 fonts, you can provide a reasonable fake in OT1 encoding with

```
\documentclass{article}

\ProvideTextCommand{\DJ}{OT1}{\raisebox{0.25ex}{-}\kern-0.4em D}

\begin{document}
\DJ
\end{document}
```

[image: Fake output]

which scales will in other point sizes thanks to @egreg pointing out than one can use `ex` and `em` units.  Note that `\newcommand` will not work in this situation because `\DJ` is defined for the T1 encoding.

Edit: as Ari Brodsky points out, the AMS classes define a fake `\DJ` command (and thorns) for `OT1` encoding.  The definition is equivalent to:

```
\ProvideTextCommand{\DJ}{OT1}{\leavevmode\raisebox{-.5ex}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip-.07em\accent"16\hss}}D}
```

producing

[image: Sample ams output]

You might want to experiment with the value of the `\hskip` in this definition to adjus the horizontal position of the bar.

Comment: You could use `ex` and `em` based length, so the constructions would be independent of the font size.

Comment: it looks like the cross on the T1 D stroke is more like an en-dash.  possibly changing the `-` in the OT1 compound to `--` with perhaps a bit of adjustment in the shifting would look more like the pre-composed one.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The length of the T1 version is somewhere between that of an ordinary dash and an en-dash.  For real fine adjustment one can use an `\hrule`.

Comment: There is also a faked version defined by the AMS document classes; see page 78 of `amsclass.pdf` (version 2.20.1):   `\DeclareTextCommand{\DJ}{OT1}{%
 \leavevmode\raisebox{-.5ex}{\makebox[\z@][l]{\hskip-.07em\accent"16\hss}}D}`

Comment: @AriBrodsky Interesting.  I have added this to my answer.