# Ugly d with stroke character (đ)

Tags: characters, font-encodings

So, is there a font in LaTeX that will reproduce decent looking d with stroke (đ)?

I'm writing a report, on Croatian, and it just looks ugly :
mwe:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,11pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}


\begin{document}

Random text random text random text with đ in it: đđđđđđđ ĐĐĐ

Oslobađajući, dođu, Đakovo    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any decent looking substitute? Garamond is nice, but the formulas seem too 'stylish' for a lab report...

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85546/15925

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the `đ`s from the [TeX Gyre](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/) fonts seem to look a lot better than those in your example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tgtermes}
%\usepackage{tgschola}
%\usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}

Random text random text random text with đ in it: đđđđđđđ ĐĐĐ

Oslobađajući, dođu, Đakovo    

\end{document}
```

The `tgtermes` package, by the way, is the contemporary version of the `txfonts` you're using, which seem to haven't been updated for more than four years.

Adobe's [Minion](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/) might be a good choice as well.

[image]

Comment: There is also the newer `newtx` (`\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`), which descends directly from `txfonts`.

Comment: newtx is principally a reworking of the metrics for use in maths -- i would not expect it to help here; newtx with tex-gyre-termes for the text might be better (and if the dbar character is bad there, the authors are in principle available, since it's a user-group-sponsored project).

Comment: @wasteofspace I know. I just wanted to address the "contemporary version of the `txfonts`" in the answer.

Comment: @wasteofspace, @mafp I didn't mean to say `tgtermes` is `txfonts`'s daughter, or, for that matter, that it's the only decent version of TNR currently available for *TeX. It is, of course, `newtx`'s sister or cousin, their common ancestor being URW's Nimbus fonts. I don't know how `newtx` compares to `tgtermes`; I just like the entire TeX Gyre project and find their fonts to be among the most advanced in their field (i.e., the open-source and *TeX world).

Answer (score 16):

The main problem is in the usage of the OT1 encoding, instead of T1; in the former, the đ and Đ characters are constructed and the construction doesn't work well with the TX fonts.

Switching to T1 has also the benefit that words containing letters with diacritics will be hyphenated properly, which doesn't happen with OT1.

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,11pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{txfonts}
```

(I don't recommend `utf8x`, but that's a matter of opinion, mostly).

You can also consider using the newTX fonts:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,11pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

that correct several glitches in the TX fonts. You may also prefer the TeX Gyre Termes fonts for text:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,11pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{tgtermes,newtxmath}
```

Here's a comparison (using TX fonts but there's practically no difference with newTX as far as the glyph shape is concerned).

[image]

Comment: The both answers are great, the `tgtermes` looks the best :) Thanks guys :)