# Smallcaps "Đ" (đ) corrupted

Tags: characters, font-encodings, small-caps

[image: Đ]

The title says it all. How do I fix it? he letter works fine when "normal" (including bold, italic, bold-italic).

I use these:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
```

Comment: Please, include this letters in the MWE, I (and not only me) have no idea how to typeset it.

Comment: You can copy and paste it from title, though... (đ Đ)

Comment: what document class are you using?  in the ams document classes, which still depend on the OT1 (7-bit) coding, the letter is constructed from an "accent" and the base letter, and i'm not sure whether small caps are properly catered for; other document classes may take the same approach.  if possible, you should use an 8-bit (T1) font encoding and `utf8` for input.

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicate; but the answer is surely `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Here it is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101107 If this answers your question, please let us know.

Comment: It fixes đ but destroys other letters, I don't like anti-aliasing and spacing, or whatever it is... It noticeably changes.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Make sure you either have the `cm-super` package installed (you don’t need to load it explicitly, though) or you load the package `lmodern`. For the differences between the two, see [Latin Modern vs cm-super?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1390).

Comment: Thanks, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}` fixed it.