# Vector arrows that cross tall characters (b, d, h, k)

Tags: math-mode, arrows, vector

The names of my vectors often have ascenders, e.g. `\vec b` and `\vec d`. By themselves, they look fine, but I have two issues with them:

- They make the letters so tall that they cause whitespace above their line;
- They look ugly next to other vectors, e.g. `\vec a`;

My goal is to *lower* the vector arrow so that it crosses the ascender when it's there, sort of how [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478587/setting-fixed-height-in-all-situations-and-characters-for-overset-notations) raises all vector arrows to the tallest height (which is the inverse of what I want). It'd look similar to bar characters (e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96479/how-can-i-type-lambda-bar) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101107/ugly-d-with-stroke-character-%c4%91)), except with a straight vector arrow, of course. If possible, it should be compatible with shifting the arrow leftward as demonstrated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460042/how-to-properly-centre-vector-arrows-upon-characters).

Comment: Since you're already using code for [shifting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460042/213149) vectors, why not do the following? `k\myvec[12mu]{}` -- add blank vector next to a tall letter and shift it back to look desirably.

Comment: @antshar I'm not using that code myself, but I knew it existed and wanted to allow people who needed both features to use both solutions.

Comment: The final result is even uglier, I'm afraid. There's a reason why the overarrow is not so frequently used nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, but I am unsure whether this looks really nice:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myvec}[2][0mu]{%
    \smash{\mkern4mu\mkern#1\relax\vec{}}%
    \mkern-4mu\mkern-#1\relax#2%
}

\begin{document}

$\myvec{a} \cdot \myvec[-1mu]{b} \cdot \myvec[6mu]{k} x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The b is acceptable, but what's up with that k? Edit: ah, the optional argument is a manual *horizontal* shift.

Comment: @Mew Yes, since you said that you would like to add an option to shift the arrow, I added this. The *kx* is just an example for this. Anyways, I think the arrow is a bit too large. Maybe it would look better with another font