# How to define a symbol for mathematics?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I need a D-stroke in Euler, but it doesn't provide one. I've made a decent one  with

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\DJ}{T1}{\raisebox{0.25ex}{-}\kern-0.4em D}
```

(taking from [Why can't I get a D with stroke?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85546/why-cant-i-get-a-d-with-stroke)), but this way I'm loosing Concrete's proper `\DJ`.

I know I could just define a different command `\DJm` instead, but I was wondering if it's possible to let LaTeX make the distinction between text and math and **I wanted to ask for some references about `\ProvideTextCommand` and `\DeclareTextCommand`.**

---

@Skillmon I've tried

```
\let\oldDJ\DJ
\DeclareTextCommand{\DJ}{T1}
{%
  \ifmmode%
    \raisebox{0.25ex}{-}\kern-0.4em D%
  \else%
    \oldDJ%
  \fi%
}
```

but I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].` I guess somehow my definition is recursive, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: You might test for math mode with `\relax\ifmmode<code for math mode>\else<code for text mode>\fi`.

Comment: I'd define `\mathDJ`

Comment: Hi @egreg, that's the kind of definition I meant with `\DJm`. It solves my problem but I was actually looking for something that wouldn't need a different command for math mode and normal text. Or some references, since I havent found anything googling for \ProvideTextCommand.

Comment: They are two different things, like `\i` and `\imath`

Comment: I know. I don't actually need Concrete's D-stroke since I will only use `\DJ` in math mode, that is in Euler. My question comes out of mere curiosity. :-) I've searched through [interface3](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) and I haven't found any instance of "\ProvideTextCommand" or "\DeclareTextCommand". So I resorted to asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define a `\mathDJ` command, but if you insist…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{concrete}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\textDJ\DJ
\let\DJ\relax

\DeclareRobustCommand{\DJ}{%
  \ifmmode
    \mathDJ
  \else
    \textDJ
  \fi
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathDJ}{\text{\raisebox{0.25ex}{-}\kern-0.4em$\m@th D$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\DJ{} and $\DJ_{\DJ}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you :-) I didn't think it had to be robust. Btw, if you or someone else can drop a link to some documentation for `\ProvideTextCommand` and `\DeclareTextCommand`, it'd be really helpful.

Comment: @ArchStanton You find something about them with `texdoc source2e`; the commands have been in LaTeX since the release of LaTeX2e

Comment: Just for completeness, the T1 encoding defines `\DH` and `\DJ`, plus the lowercase `\dh` and `\dj`. `\DH` and `\DJ` look identical in the OP's font, but `\dh` and `\dj` are different - `\dh` is like a "partial derivative with a slash" but `\dh` is an upright lowercase d with a slash.